# Bash script if statement followed by multiple OR's

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I have the problem that I want an if statement that makes sure the first statement is true and  one or more of the following three statement are also true in a bash script.

The code I currently have is:

```
if [[ $TAIL != "true" ]] && [[ -f $FILE_DIR/.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../../.completed ]]
```

I have also tried:

```
if [[ $TAIL != "true" ]] && [[ [[ -f $FILE_DIR/.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../../.completed ]] ]]
```

but neither work.

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance for help.

The answer is as shown below:

```
if [[ $TAIL != "true" ]] && ( [[ -f $FILE_DIR/.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../../.completed ]] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all inside one [[]]:

```
if [[ $TAIL != "true" && ( -f $FILE_DIR/.completed || -f $FILE_DIR/../.completed || -f $FILE_DIR/../../.completed ) ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for additional answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can group your OR statements with parentheses:

```
if [[ $TAIL != "true" ]] && ( [[ -f $FILE_DIR/.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../.completed ]] || [[ -f $FILE_DIR/../../.completed ]] )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for quick and simple solution.